# two errors while using classes in main function c++

Tags: c++, class, program-entry-point

I have two errors while using classes in my main function.

first error -

```
error C2227: left of '->digitarray' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
```

The second error is -

```
error C2675: unary '~' : 'game' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
```

The header file -

```
class game{
private:
    int cows();
    int bulls();
    bool game_over = false;

public:
    int x;
    number *user, *computer;
    game();
    ~game();
    game(const number,const number);
    void play();
};
```

The main file -

```
int main(){
    game();
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        cout << game::computer->digitarray[i].value;
    } 

    ~game();

}
```

And the "number" header file -

```
#define SIZE 4

class number{
private:
public:
    digit digitarray[SIZE];
    number();
    void numscan();
    void randomnum();
    int numreturn(int);
    void numprint();
};
```

Comment: __No, you don't call destructors yourself!__

Comment: And having a standalone constructor call is wrong also. Just declare a variable of type `game`.

Comment: The computer variable is a non-static member variable. Such variables can be accessed only using an object. And the destructor should not be called explicitly.

Comment: @Akra _"Regarding the destructor, how do I call it then?"_ You don't need to. The compiler does that automatically if a variable goes out of scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix is very simple, declare a variable of type `game`:

```
int main(){
    game g;
      // ^^
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        cout << g.computer->digitarray[i].value;
             // ^^
    } 

    // ~game(); <<< You don't need this or g.~game();
}   // <<< That's done automatically here
```

Answer (score 0):

Following things are wrong with your code.

1) You have not created objected and trying the access the class member, this can only be done for static class members.

2) You cannot call destructor explicitly.

Comment: 2) - actually you can :)